# Establish whether a node is NEW in a custom #submit function

Tags: nodes, 8

I need to test whether a user is creating a new node as opposed to editing an existing node in a custom #submit function added to a node edit/creation form.

I can access the node via

```
$node = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity();
```

$node->id() - gives the new node ID so cant be used.

$node->get('nid')  - also gives an gives the new node ID so cant be used.

$node->isNew() - This is actually FALSE in this hook despite it being new content.

Comment: Also, looking inside $node the ['values']['nid']['x-default'] is an empty array when the content is new and filled when it isn't however i cant seem to find a 'getter' to get that information out of the object.

Comment: Sounds like the form submit is called _after_ the node was saved.

Comment: Yup, that sounds like the case however i need to find a way of making the determination at this point in time.

Comment: Could you use hook_node_presave() instead? See: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!node!src!Entity!Node.php/function/Node%3A%3ApreSave/8.2.x

Comment: Sorry, it is now hook_entity_presave: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_presave/8.2.x

Comment: On the basis of whether the node is new or not i need to call        $form_state->setRedirectUrl() which i don't think ill be able to do in node_presave()

Comment: Ok, I didn't have that information upfront. Would you be able to do a hook_form_alter instead, and on node content forms, add your own submission hook? It should be easy to determine from that level if the node is new or not.

Comment: The hook above is actually a submit function i added to the node form via ['#submit'][] = 'hook_form_node_form_submit' so that is the situation i am already in.

Comment: Did you change the weight of it so it executes first?

Comment: There isn't any `hook_form_node_form_submit()` hook that is used from Drupal 8, nor Drupal 7.

Comment: @kiamlaluno if you read my comment (two above yours) you will see that i explained i had added it in a #submit function, but youre right i shouldnt have technically called it a 'hook'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this method:

```
if ($form_state->getFormObject()->getOperation() == 'edit') {
  // existing node 
}
```

These are the operations defined for node:

```
 "form" = {
   "default" = "Drupal\node\NodeForm",
   "delete" = "Drupal\node\Form\NodeDeleteForm",
   "edit" = "Drupal\node\NodeForm"
 },
```

Comment: Ah... this looks like the way forward, when adding a new node at this point i get 'default' but when editing i get 'edit' so i think the is the distinction i am looking for.

Comment: You are right. I checked in the node entity. For nodes there is no 'add', I put this information in the answer.

Comment: This is an interesting question, and curiosity got to me and I had to trace this out.  EntityForm sets the submit handlers for Save to [::submitForm, ::save].  This means that NodeForm::submitForm then NodeForm::save get called, the later of which sets up the form redirect.  So, to override the redirect, you have to do this after; so have to have the custom submit handler on the end of the array (which the OP did).  I am curious, though, whether there is a better option in $form or $form_state to use.

Comment: There should be no problem with `getOperation()`, but you have to check in the entity type definition. If 'add' and 'edit' is not defined, drupal uses 'default' when building the route, see https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!Routing!DefaultHtmlRouteProvider.php/function/DefaultHtmlRouteProvider%3A%3AgetEditFormRoute/8.2.x

Answer (score 0):

You can implement hook_entity_presave to look at an entity on create/update:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_presave/8.2.x

Just implement some logic to check that the entity is a Node, and that it is either isNew() or has no id(), then put your logic inside of that.